# Django local static files path puzzle

Tags: python, django, static, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to render static files locally in development. I have followed the rules and placed stylesheets in `/static/` in my Django project folder, setting `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`. Using the `{{ STATIC_URL }}` template tag works and the paths rendered in the document head point to the correct directory (as far as I can tell), e.g.:

```
http://localhost:8000/static/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

This returns a 404, and of course, there's no styling.

I started with `/static` and its contents (i.e. `/css/bootstrap.min.css`) in the project root folder. I then copied it and its entire contents to all the other app directories, to try different places Django might be looking. Still 404.

Relevant settings in `settings.py`:

```
DEBUG = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'south',
    'users',
    'registration',
    'django_extensions',
    'django.contrib.admin',
)
```

What's going wrong?

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your `urls.py` look like? Have you forgotten to include a static files url? If you look at the documentation on serving static files https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development it suggests putting the following in `urls.py`

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

# ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Comment: That works. I had considered that option but was convinced otherwise by the following line in the docs:

`This view is automatically enabled and will serve your static files at STATIC_URL when you use the built-in runserver management command. To enable this view if you are using some other server for local development, you'll add a couple of lines to your URLconf.`

Since I am using runserver, I inferred that the URLconf stuff was unnecessary. But you are right, thanks.

Comment: I'm glad it sorted your problem, but I read the docs the same way you do, so I think it's probably not the right thing to do. Do you definitely have `django.contrib.staticfiles` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`? Or perhaps you have something in your urls.py which catches everything after, so that the url from the staticfiles app never gets reached?

Comment: `staticfiles` is an installed app, as you say. I don't have the staticfiles context processor in, but that comes by default (which is why the tag is working). I can't see anything in urls that is causing trouble, but I'll be alive to that point in future troubleshoots. Sounds like the problem could very well be there. Thanks!